# Symfony - pack data

Tags: php, function, symfony

I wrote a function where I passed all of the params for adding a user.

```
 public function userAddAction()
{

    $this->requirePostParams(['username', 'usernameCanonical', 'email', 'emailCanonical', 'password', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'birthDay',
                              'addressOne', 'addressTwo', 'city', 'country', 'postCode', 'mobile', 'about']);

    $this->get('user')->addNewUser($this->data['username'], $this->data['usernameCanonical'], $this->data['email'],
                                             $this->data['password'], $this->data['emailCanonical'], $this->data['firstName'],
                                             $this->data['lastName'], $this->data['birthDay'],  $this->data['addressOne'],
                                             $this->data['addressTwo'], $this->data['city'], $this->data['country'], $this->data['postCode'],
                                             $this->data['mobile'], $this->data['about']);

    return $this->success();
}

protected function requirePostParams($params)
{
    $currentRequest = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    $postData = $currentRequest->request->all();

    $postContent = json_decode($currentRequest->getContent(), true);

    if (!empty($postContent)) {
        $postData = $postContent;
    }

    $this->data = $postData;

    $missingParams = [];

    foreach ($params as $param) {
        if (!array_key_exists($param, $postData)) {
            $missingParams[] = $param;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($missingParams)) {
        $this->terminateWithResponse($this->jsonError(sprintf("Missing params: %s", join(', ', $missingParams))));
    }
}
```

Now, I want to pack all of $this->data .... into just one call to reduce all the fields I need to type..

Comment: Without info about `$this->requirePostParams()` or `$this->data` we can't help you. Why don't you use Symfony Forms?

Comment: What does `requirePostParams` do? Perhaps you can use Symfony forms for this?

Comment: Currently I am using Postman to test. I updated my post. @StephanVIerkent

Comment: What do you mean by "pack"? Why don't you just transfert the whole `$this->data` array to the function that needs all that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [Symfony Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) here.

Usually you need to just call something like that:

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

But as I understand you have json string in your Request. So instead of `handleRequest`, after you've set up `$this->data`, you need to call `$form->submit($this->data);`

You can take a look at this method [HttpFoundationRequestHandler::handleRequest](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php) and it will help you understand better of how Forms actually work with Request.